# Code generation for `sum` function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

In cross correlation we use the below command to calculate the sum after elementary multiplication of the vectors. But when we try to convert this Matlab code to vhdl using HDL coder, this command is not defined by `HDL` coder. Is it possible to write code for below line without using '`sum' builtin` function please.

```
xc(i)=sum((y1(j1:k1)).*y2(j2:k2));
```

where `j1`, `j2`, `k1` and `k2` are the starting and ending limits.
`y1` and `y2` are two vectors and are being multiplied element wise and the result is being added.

Thanks

Comment: Well, yeah... Using *for* loop would we the easiest way...

Comment: @jojek, Thanks for the reply.Can you please elaborate little bit further.I will really appreciate it!

Comment: `sum` becomes a loop that sums all the elements to the accumulator. Anyway I don't understand why are you trying to do that since [**sum is supported by HDL Coder**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/ug/functions-supported-for-hdl-code-generation-alphabetical-list.html)

Comment: @jojek  Thanks for the link. Even if sum is supported by hdl coder,still I am getting error :
 MATLAB for code generation only supports SumModes 'SpecifyPrecision' and 'KeepLSB' for 'SUM' when the size of the inputs can vary at run-time.    Can you please comment on it.Why this error?

Comment: You have to specify how to calculate the sum will be calculated for Fixed-Point object. Take a look at [**fimath**](http://bit.ly/1W2Xyoi) specification of *SumMode* and choose the position of your radix point, or simply use the *KeepLSB* - I suggest it. All of that is due to the way Fixed Point math is being done and how you have to "juggle" with both precision and overflows. For variable input size it is obviously difficult to determine how much dynamic range you need. Also please have a look on the example for [**product and sum**](http://bit.ly/1OojkxG). All of that should get you started.

Comment: @jojek Thanks, I will go through it and see what comes out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34192/discussion-between-jojek-and-haider).

Comment: @jojek It would be so nice if you respond to my comment in chat please. I would really appreciate your time.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the size of `y1(j1:k1)` and `y2(j2:k2)` must be the same then:
$$
k_1-j_1 = k_2-j_2
$$
and you will also have something like: $j_1+N=j_2$ then you could write a for loop like this:

```
xc(i) = 0
for n=j1:k1
  xc(i) = xc(i) + y1(n)*y2(n+N)
end
```